# Can I delete directories in /var without verified signatures (NO_PUBKEY Error) in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, administrator, apt-get, cuda

When I execute `sudo apt-get update` command I get the following terminal output:

```
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-7-local  InRelease [1.575 B]
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local  Release [564 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-7-local  InRelease [1.575 B]
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local  Release [564 B]
(...)                                           
(...)
(...)
Err:9 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local  Release.gpg                                                                                      
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 
F60F4B3D7FA2AF80
(...)
(...)
(...)
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [710 kB]
Fetched 7.512 kB in 2s (4.169 kB/s)                        
Reading package lists... Done
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/hhtps could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-hhtps installed?
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and
the previous index files will be used. GPG error: file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local 
Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:
NO_PUBKEY F60F4B3D7FA2AF80
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as (...)
E: Failed to fetch hhtps://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/dists/xenial/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local/Release.gpg  The following
signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY
F60F4B3D7FA2AF80
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am concerned with the errors/warnings about `/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local/Release.gpg`. I have checked with `ls /var/` and there is a newer cuda-repo that I just installed manually, however, I do not feel confident deleting the older repo.
Therefore my question is:

1. should delete the outdated, unverified directory from `/var` or,
2. is there another 'clean' method to handle this or,
3. is the repo still relevant and should be kept despite the warning?
4. other...

What is the best practice to get rid of this warning?

I appreciate your help!

Cheers,

Luis

Comment: Note the line `N: Is the package apt-transport-hhtps installed?`. While there is a typo in there, it should point you into the right direction. Try `sudo apt install apt-transport-https`

Comment: Hi, that is not a typo. I have already wondered about that, but apparently this has something to do with the desktop signal app and is not related to my question. Apt-transport-https is installed though.

Comment: Well, apart from that you have a repository which throws an key error, [you might want to get rid of it](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/remove-an-apt-repository-ubuntu)

Comment: @mashuptwice, i think this is exactly what i wanted. The deletion of that specific key was part of the more recent installation. The link you posted shows how to get rid of the repository. Thank you! I will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mashuptwice already stated in the comments, that deleting the erroneous repository is the solution. Doing so properly is explained [here](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/remove-an-apt-repository-ubuntu).
Command line tools like `add-apt-repository` and `ppa-purge` are used.